# JS - Calculate values depending on selected dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this calculator for money that shows you the amount you enter but in a different money value. (Example dollar to euro)

Here is the HTML:

```
    <b> Exchange money </b> <br> <br>
Enter amount for RSD: <input type="number" name="nbsAmount" id="nbsAmount" size="5"> <br>
<button class="dugme">Calculate</button> <br> <br>
Evro value is: <div class="konacnaEvroVrednost"></div>
Dolar value is: <div class="konacnaDolarVrednost"></div>
Swiss value is: <div class="konacnaSwissrednost"></div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
$('.dugme').click(function(){
   var broj = document.getElementById('nbsAmount').value;   
   var evro = broj * 0.0085;
   var dolar = broj * 0.0095;
   var frank = broj * 0.0096;
   $('.konacnaEvroVrednost').text(evro + ' €');  
   $('.konacnaDolarVrednost').text(dolar + ' $');  
   $('.konacnaSwissrednost').text(frank + ' Fr');  
});
```

And this works fine. As you can see:

[image]

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5zvdwtpL/1/

But now I want to change this to work a bit more dynamically.
I want there to be two dropdowns that lets you select the value you want to change from to. Like this:
[image]

This is what I got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/7s8g9kLt/2/

**The problem** is that one input value should be copied to the other input value but with the added value of the currency.

So If I select RSD and set 1200, the other USD, then the other input should display 11.4.

So I am stuck a bit here as to how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have bound `myFunction` to button onClick Event but you have not defined function with this name. You can see following error in console after clicking button

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
```

You will have to define this function:

```
window.myFunction = function() {...}
```

or event better, add event listener to button click:

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').addEventListener('click', function() {...})
```

---

To calculate dynamic rates, i would first convert input amount to single currency (for example RSD) and then multiply that value by correct rate.

I've modified your jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/rhj4dgz7/3/) to reflect those changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary with the pair of "id" of dropdown and the conversion rate, also you can give the same id to both drop downs. then you gonna just multiply the value by the rate and add the result to the second input.

```
var rsd = 1;
var evro = 0.0085;

var dolar = 0.0095;
var frank = 0.0096;

var dict = {
"4":rsd,
"1":evro,
"3":dolar,
"2":frank
}



function myFunction(){
var mvs = document.getElementById('mojaVrednostSelect').value;
var nvs = document.getElementById('novaVrednostSelect').value;

var mv = document.getElementById('mojaVrednost').value;
var nv = document.getElementById('novaVrednost').value;
novaVrednost.value =  parseInt(mojaVrednost.value) * dict[nvs]
console.log("Yoooo"+  dict[nvs])
console.log("mvs je" + mvs);
console.log("nvs je" + nvs);
console.log("======");
console.log("mojaVrednost je" + mojaVrednost.value);
console.log("novaVrednost je" + novaVrednost.value);
}
document.getElementById('button').onclick = myFunction
```

[check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lncjugq7/3/)

Hope this helps you